# Cmake can't finde "XCB"

Tags: cmake, vulkan, xcb

I am trying to install the Vulkan SDK on my Linux Mint Machine, but I have problems with building it.
When I type `cmake .. -Wno-dev` 
I get this output

```
-- Using cmake find_program to look for glslangValidator
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:60 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindXCB.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "XCB", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "XCB" with any of
  the following names:

    XCBConfig.cmake
    xcb-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "XCB" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "XCB_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "XCB" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/heimchen/Downloads/1.3.204.1/source/Vulkan-Tools/cube/build/CmakeFiles/CmakeOutput.log"
```

- I already tried to remove `libxcb1-dev` and reinstalled it.\
- I already tried to remove`libxcb-randr0-dev` and reinstalled it.
- I already tried to remove `libwayland-dev` and reinstalled it.

Edit:

It compiles at `1.3.204.1/source/Vulkan-Tools`, but I still have some ERRORs with missing packages. `CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):   A required package was not found Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:643 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)   cmake/FindWaylandProtocols.cmake:9 (pkg_check_modules)   cube/CMakeLists.txt:70 (find_package)`\

Edit:
Tried it two days later and it worked. Don't know why.

Comment: You need to use `1.3.204.1/source/Vulkan-Tools` as a **source** directory. Using its subdirectory - `1.3.204.1/source/Vulkan-Tools/cube` - as a source doesn't work.

Comment: As you could find, *comments* are not suitable for multiline error message. Instead, we expect the **question post** to contain all relevant information about the problem. Please, update your question post.

Comment: Have you installed `libwayland-dev` package, as described in the [build guide](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools/blob/master/BUILD.md)?

Comment: I had it already installed, removed and reinstalled it, but I still have the same ERROR message

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the problem for me:

```
$ sudo apt install libxcb-xfixes0-dev
```

Comment: Be sure to use markdown formatting in your answer, to make them visually clearer